# gcc inline the generic template function with a specialized definition

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, inline, compiler-optimization

I doubt if gcc 4.8.3 inlines incorrect template functions... This problem does not occur in debug mode, but only in optimized mode. However this happens in a complicated code base, I am not able to reproduce the issue in a simple test case.

My code is like the following

```
#include "stdio.h"

class A {
 public:

    template<typename T> int WriteNative(const T) { 
      printf("here?\n")
      return 0; 
    }

    template<typename D> 
        void doit() {
        if (WriteNative<double>(1)) {
            printf("A\n");
        } else {
            printf("B\n");
        }
    }

};

// in my real code, this definition is in a different cpp file
template<> int A::WriteNative<double>(const double) { 
  return 1; 
}

int main() {
    A a;
    a.doit<float>();
}
```

In debug build, it prints out A, while in optimized build, it prints out here?\nB

I guess any inliner uses the generic template function definition but not the specialized one. But **attribute** ((noinline)) does not help.

Does anyone if my code has a defined behavior of C++? and how to fix this issue?

Comment: My workaround I found is by inlining the specialized definitions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445654/multiple-definition-of-template-specialization-when-using-different-objects.

Answer (score 2):

You don't state this explicitly, but I'd guess in your actual code you were failing to declare the specialization in `A`'s .h file. So when `A.h` was included in a separate compilation unit, the compiler was unaware of the specializatoin of `WriteNative()`. Adding a declaration of the specialization should fix the issue without having to include the definition in the same file (i.e., not having to inline it):

```
class A {
    public:
    template<typename T> int WriteNative(const T) { 
      printf("here?\n")
      return 0; 
    }

    template<typename D> 
        void doit() {
        if (WriteNative<double>(1)) {
            printf("A\n");
        } else {
            printf("B\n");
        }
    }
};
template<> int A::WriteNative(const double);
```

You can reproduce your issue by using three files `A.h`, `A.cpp`, and `main.cpp`, where `A.cpp` contains the definition of the specialization, so that when `main.cpp` includes `A.h`, it is unaware of the specialization when inlining happens during optimization, and when compiled with `-O0`, no inlining occurs, so `WriteNative()` gets linked against the definition in `A.cpp`.

Edit:
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190424/c-linking-and-template-specializations#7190915) which cites the spec to explain why this is correct behavior.

14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec]:

> 6/ If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is
>   explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared
>   before the first use of that specialization that would cause an
>   implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in
>   which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required. If the program
>   does not provide a definition for an explicit specialization and
>   either the specialization is used in a way that would cause an
>   implicit instantiation to take place or the member is a virtual member
>   function, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. An
>   implicit instantiation is never generated for an explicit
>   specialization that is declared but not defined.

Comment: Is declaring the specialization in the header file requested by C++?

Comment: It is not. But then other compilation units will not see it, obviously. This is a matter of what happens during compilation and what happens during linkage

Comment: @n.caillou If it is not required, the optimization seems too aggressive to me. I think a compiler optimization should not change how code works unless my original code w/o the declaration is undefined.

Comment: But your compiler doesn't know that an `A.cpp` file exists when it's compiling `main.o`. You're denying the entire per-unit compilation procedure.

Comment: I agree that with this assumption, more code can be optimized. However I think this is also similar to optimizing "bool b; b = false; if (b) ... " where b is a global. Compilers would not replace b by false because other files can "extern b" and assign other values to 'b'. How is this different from function template specialization?